# Problem getting rotations for corrective blendshapes with Rigify

Tags: shape-keys, rigify

I am not hopeful to getting an answer to this, as I found an earlier post asking a similar question that has no answers, but here goes.

I am animating a character using the rig generated by Rigify from the Human Metarig I want to use corrective blendshapes to fix the shape of areas like the knees and elbows as they flex, but I am having trouble finding anything on the IK rig that can act as a driver. When I bend the leg up using the IK controller at the foot, and then explore the parts of the rig, I can't find anything that has rotational values, even though the knee is bent to the max.

Is there some layer that I haven't discovered that actually shows the rotational position of the parts that are deforming the character? so far, the only option I can think of is to use the vertical axis of the IK controller, but this is imprecise at best and really only workable at all for the knee, but not the elbows or other joints.

If anyone knows anything that could help me figure out this situation, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using the deform bones as inputs to the drivers.  IIRC, these are on the very last layers, like layers 30,31,32.  Anything named def-whatever.  Use the actual armature layers, not Rigify's layer-like interface-- I don't think Rigify will show you the deform layers from the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the def part.  Although I still haven't figured out where they are in the layer system, I was able to do what I wanted by adding the right DEF bone and axis in the driver panel.  I was looking to select the bone and copy as driver, but that really isn't necessary. Thanks again for the help.